# Linear optimization constrained by cost function

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Suppose I have an optimization problem of the form:

$$\min \mathbf{d}^{T}\mathbf{y}$$

subject to

$$\mathbf{M}\mathbf{y} \geq  \mathbf{d}, \qquad \mathbf{y} \geq 0$$

If a solution $\mathbf{s}$ which satisfies $\mathbf{M}\mathbf{s} = \mathbf{d}$ and $\mathbf{s} \geq 0$, how can it be shown $\mathbf{s}$ is optimal for the above linear programming problem?

Initial thought was to form the dual:

max p'd

p>=0

p'M<=d

Thus weak duality gives
d'y <= p'd

And the constraint of the dual gives p'M<=d

so : p'My<=dy

and thus p'd<=dy

Combining the two equalities shows that p'd must equal dy, and thus with strong duality this means that p'd is the optimal solution.

Where did I go wrong, and how does being symmetric fit into the problem?

Comment: How do $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{c}$ relate to the original problem?

Comment: Whoops! Sorry I meant Ms = d, not c...typo!

Comment: It isn't the case that $s$ is necessarily optimal.  I found a counterexample.  Are you missing anything from the problem statement?  Maybe that ${\bf M}^T = {\bf M}$?

Comment: Yes actually, M^t = M, but how does this play in to the problem? You are good!

Comment: Thanks.  I *teach* this stuff. :)  As with the other question you asked, what are your thoughts so far?  (You can just add them as an edit to the end of your original post rather than as a new comment.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go this route: You know **Ms** = **d**.  Taking transposes, you have **s**$^T$ **M**$^T$ = **d**$^T$.  But (the key step) since **M**$^T$ = **M**, this means that **s** is feasible for the dual problem.  Since **s** is feasible for the primal and for the dual, and since the primal and dual have the same objective function, weak duality shows you that **s** must be optimal.

If **M**$^T \neq $ **M** then **s** might not be optimal.  For example, suppose we have the following linear program.

$$\min x + y$$

subject to

$$\frac{1}{2}x + y \geq 1,$$
$$\frac{1}{2}x + 2y \geq 1,$$
$$x,y \geq 0.$$

The objective and right-hand side coefficient vectors are the same, as in the problem statement.  Solving the inequalities at equality gives you $x = 2$, $y=0$.  However, this is not optimal.  The solution $x = 0$, $y = 1$ yields a smaller objective function value (and is actually the optimal solution).